# Which Data Set?

Tags: python, dataset

I am learning how to organize data with Python and have come to a wall when trying to decide which dataset would be best. This is something like a database. The phone number would be the primary key, each phone number can have multiple message numbers and message numbers can only have one message, but if they are within a close range, let's say 2 or 3, the messages should be combined. If the message numbers are not close, they should become a new message entry.

What data set would suit this structure?

```
|Phone#|   Phone#    |
|------|------|------|
| msg# | msg# | msg# |
|------|------|------|
| msg  | msg  | msg  |
| body | body | body |
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "data set". Do you mean which object or data structure? If that's the case, it could be anything form a sql database to a nested dictionary to a dataframe to JSON, etc. It really depends too much on your use case for us to be able to answer well

Comment: Yes, I mean data structure, sorry. Basically, I just run a script to pull some data from a website then collate that data into a readable format. I have the parts broken into variables, but I am unsure of how to format this in the most efficient way. If one method is easier than the others that's what I would lean towards.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are good for these sorts of things.  As you described it, the phone number would be the key to the dictionary, and for each phone number the message number would be a key (another dictionary) for a single message.  You will need to think about the best way to combine messages with close numbers, but in general a dictionary with sub-dictionaries could meet your needs.

Example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

phone_message_data = [
("662-637-7807", 8, "mauris viverra diam vitae quam suspendisse potenti nullam porttitor lacus"),
("802-193-7590", 23, "donec semper sapien a libero nam dui proin"),
("372-408-8780", 7, "donec ut dolor morbi vel"),
("472-780-0344", 15, "curabitur gravida nisi at nibh in hac"),
("860-191-8245", 31, "dapibus dolor vel est donec odio justo sollicitudin ut"),
("160-212-2277", 72, "potenti in eleifend quam a odio in hac habitasse platea"),
("860-191-8245", 33, "sit amet eleifend pede libero quis orci nullam molestie nibh"),
("710-810-6711", 10, "nec nisi volutpat eleifend donec ut dolor morbi"),
("611-834-8815", 36, "posuere nonummy integer non velit donec diam neque vestibulum"),
("312-909-1365", 3, "pellentesque viverra pede ac diam cras pellentesque"),
]

phone_messages = defaultdict(dict)

for phone_number, message_number, message_text in phone_message_data:
    phone_messages[phone_number][message_number] = message_text

pprint(phone_messages)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,
            {'160-212-2277': {72: 'potenti in eleifend quam a odio in hac '
                                  'habitasse platea'},
             '312-909-1365': {3: 'pellentesque viverra pede ac diam cras '
                                 'pellentesque'},
             '372-408-8780': {7: 'donec ut dolor morbi vel'},
             '472-780-0344': {15: 'curabitur gravida nisi at nibh in hac'},
             '611-834-8815': {36: 'posuere nonummy integer non velit donec '
                                  'diam neque vestibulum'},
             '662-637-7807': {8: 'mauris viverra diam vitae quam suspendisse '
                                 'potenti nullam porttitor lacus'},
             '710-810-6711': {10: 'nec nisi volutpat eleifend donec ut dolor '
                                  'morbi'},
             '802-193-7590': {23: 'donec semper sapien a libero nam dui proin'},
             '860-191-8245': {31: 'dapibus dolor vel est donec odio justo '
                                  'sollicitudin ut',
                              33: 'sit amet eleifend pede libero quis orci '
                                  'nullam molestie nibh'}})
```

Comment: Ah, I was unaware that a dictionary could hold another dictionary. Thanks for the answer! Is it possible to dynamically create the dictionaries from a variable based on the pulled data, ie phone numbers?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to dynamically create the dictionaries based on pulled data instead of reading the data from the `phone_message_data` list.  Instead, wrap the code in a function and pass the phone number, message number, and message text to it as parameters as you pull it.